# Proper way to check if many-to-many relation exists - Symfony2/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Let's suppose I have two entities User and Product related by a Many-to-Many relationship with Doctrine.

I would like to know the best way to handle a $user->hasProduct($product) method for my User entity that returns true is relation exists or false if not.

I'm currently doing this :

```
public function hasProduct($id)
{
    foreach($this->getProducts() as $product) {
        if($product->getId() == $id) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But i'm not sure it's the best way, especially if there is many relations in the loop.

If someone has something better, let me know :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your function `getProducts` gives you an `ArrayCollection`.

Just do

```
if($user->getProducts()->contains($product)) //the real product object not the id
       //your stuff
```

**Edit :**

For twig template :

```
{% if product in user.products %}
    //your stuff
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sounds good ! I will use that. Is there a way to perform this in twig templates ?

Comment: And what if I want to check e.g. if product with a given name exits?

Comment: You have to manually loop through the products or use a custom `DQL` query

Comment: Note: You don't actually need to fetch the object prior to using `contains()`. A lazy reference is good enough, which you can obtain with `$product = $em->getReference('MyBundle:MyProduct', $id)`. This will not cause an DB query.

Comment: How do you check the opposite in twig? if it’s not in user.product?

Comment: @MilesM. 
That would be
    {% if product not in user.products %}
        //your stuff
    {% endif %}

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the same problem, and came across [this](https://www.boxuk.com/insight/blog-posts/filtering-associations-with-doctrine-2) blog entry which solved this problem by making use of Doctrine Filters.

If I understand your problem correctly and you have three tables (user, user_product and product) you should be able to rewrite your hasProduct($id) function like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

public function hasProduct(int $productId): bool {

  $criteria = Criteria::create();
  $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('id', $productId));

  if(count($this->products->matching($criteria)) > 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

When running this code, Doctrine does not load all the Products linked to the User. It in fact only queries the cross reference table (user_product).